# Getting package name from Cargo.toml for another directory from inside another one in Rust

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and am trying to query a package name of another Rust project having a Cargo.toml package from a parent Rust project set up in a different directory.
If I query package_name as,

```
let package_name: String = env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME").to_string();
```

I get the package_name of the parent directory I am querying from. Is there any way to change the environment to the new directory I want to query the package from? Both the paths are known to me.

Comment: Those environment variables give you information about the current crate being compiled and are completely independent from your current directory. You can use the [`toml`](https://crates.io/crates/toml) crate to parse the `Cargo.toml` in another project.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what is the usecase? I wonder where this would be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the `toml` crate. This solution attempts to read `Cargo.toml` in a specified directory then returns the `name` field of the `package`.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufReader, Error, ErrorKind, Read};
use std::path::Path;
use toml::Value;

fn find_package_name<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> io::Result<String> {
    let cargo_toml = path.as_ref().join("Cargo.toml");

    let mut reader = BufReader::new(File::open(cargo_toml)?);
    let mut buffer = Vec::new();
    reader.read_to_end(&mut buffer)?;

    let data: Value = toml::from_slice(&buffer[..])?;

    let name_field = data
        .get("package")
        .and_then(|x| x.get("name"))
        .and_then(Value::as_str);

    match name_field {
        Some(x) => Ok(x.to_owned()),
        None => Err(Error::new(
            ErrorKind::Other,
            "Unable to find package name in toml",
        )),
    }
}
```

Environment variables such as `CARGO_PKG_NAME` are set only once when the crate is compiled to give a crate context about the compiler configuration. These do not change no matter where a project is compiled or run from.